# When I'm insert any data it gives me a 302 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, ajaxform, signaturepad

I want to Insert my signaturepad. I have taken the reference from  https://codepen.io/BigLeeBrink/pen/ZdvLLE

Below is my controller code:

```
 public function actionSignaturesave()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->post('case_id') != '') {

            $case_id = Yii::$app->request->post('case_id', '');
            $signatureData = Yii::$app->request->post('signature_image');

                if($signatureData != "")
                {
                    $signatureData = 'data:image/png;base64,'.$signatureData;
                    $filePath = Yii::$app->params['uploadpath'].'casesignature'.'/'.  $model->case_id.'.png';
                    file_put_contents($filePath, file_get_contents($signatureData));
                    $urlatt = Yii::$app->urlManagerApi->createAbsoluteUrl('common/addmedia');
                    $newthumb = 0; 
                    $tempname = $filePath;
                    $filetype = $this->commonModel->getFileTypeWithExtension($tempname);
                    $allowExtenssion = ["jpg","jpeg","png","gif","JPG","JPEG","PNG","GIF"];
                    if (in_array($filetype['extension'], $allowExtenssion) || count($allowExtenssion) == 0) {
                        $paramsatt = array(
                            "unitId" => @Yii::$app->session->get('user.unitId'),
                            "Title" => 'Signature Attachment Image',
                            "extension" => $filetype['extension'],
                            "ref_table" => 118,
                            "ref_id" =>   $model->case_id,
                            "file_type" => $filetype['type'],
                            "link" => "",
                            "isthumb" => $newthumb,
                            "is_external_link" => 0,
                        );
                        $resp = $this->commonModel->callApi($urlatt, $paramsatt, $tempname);
                    }
                   
                }
                return $this->redirect('casedetail');
                
        } else {
            echo $this->functionModel->_jsonencode(['Status' => 500, 'Message' => \Yii::t('frontend', "something_went_wrong")]);
        }
    }
```

Here i have taken a one hidden input when i clicks on submit it's shows me my basecode64 url in value of hidden input type.
Model Code:-
 Url::to(['defect/inspectionadd']), 'options' => ['id' => 'defect-inspection-add-form']]);
?>

  case_status == 4)
  {
  ?>
- 

'save-signature', 'class'=>'save-signature']); ?>
Save
Clear






$this->registerJs("
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var canvas = document.getElementById('signature');
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

```
        $('#save-signature').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var Sigimage=signaturePad.toDataURL();
            // console.log(Sigimage);
            document.getElementsByName('signature_image')[0].setAttribute('value', Sigimage);
   
            signaturePad.clear();
        });

        $('#clear-signature').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            signaturePad.clear();
        });
        
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#save-signature', function(){
        var params = new Object();        
        params.case_id = '" . $model->case_id . "';
        params.image =  document.getElementsByName('signature_image').value;
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  :  '" . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('case/signaturesave') . "',
            data :  params, 
            success : function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                if(data.Status != 200)
                {
                    iplus.alert(data.Message);
                    return false;
                }
        }
    });
        return false;
    });
");
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! so, in short, you got `302` when you throw `500`?

Comment: Yes When I'm trying to insert data it's giving me 302 Error

Comment: did the data inserted? if it is, you might hit `$this->redirect('casedetail');` part, am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This part is what's causing the server to respond with `302 Found`

```php
return $this->redirect('casedetail');
```

The `redirect` method sets response status to `302` and sends the url the browser should be redirected to in `Location` header.

From your javascript I would assume that you want to send JSON object with `Status` and `Message` properties. The proper way to do it in Yii 2 would be like this:

```
$response = Yii::$app->response;
$response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
$response->data = [
    'Status' => 200,
    'Message' => 'some success message',
];
return $response;
```

This will cause server to respond properly with something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
... some other headers ...

{"Status":200,"Message":"some success message"}
```

You should also replace this error status response generation with proper way described above.

```
echo $this->functionModel->_jsonencode(...)
```

If you want you can set the proper status code for response with:

```php
$response->statusCode = 500;
```

If your response properly declare `application/json` as content type, you don't need to call `JSON.parse()` in your `success` callback because the json is already parsed for you when the data are passed to success callback.